# How can I get AD authentication without joining a domain?

Tags: samba, active-directory

In order for me to configure `Samba` to use the `Windows Active Directory` authentication, do I need to join a domain? Can I do that without joining the domain?

Comment: Seems like you should read this: http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_%26_Active_Directory

Comment: It seem to me that it has no way to do it unless I join domain.

Answer (score 2):

I almost didn't answer because the follow-up post looked like a 'bump' post.

You can get AD-like passwords without joining the domain via the pam_smb package.  It *only* does password checking, and doesn't check groups, GPOs, nothing.  We've used it in the past, and it coexists with other auth methods well, and even authenticates over a VPN (eg vtun) to a far remote ad box.